# How to access an array defined and declared in one function in another function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Can anyone tell me how to access an array declared and defined in a function in another function.
I defined class.

```
class main_menu
{ 
    public:             
        void random_number();
        void search_array();
};
```

Then I defined two functions :

```
void main_menu :: random_number()
{
    // Size is global variable so I can access to this variable anywhere.
    long random_digit[Size]; 
}

void main_menu :: search_array()
{
   I want to access random_digit[Size]   here.
}
```

I wish someone help me. Thanks .

Comment: Make `random_digit` a global variable to begin with?

Comment: Make it a member of your class instead. `Size` should probably also be a member instead of a global.

Comment: Make `random_digit` a member of the class `main_menu`, rather than local to any of its member functions.

Comment: *"Size is global variable"*, I hope `Size` is `const`, else you use VLA extension which is not standard.

Comment: I will put my code here. You can download it and check it. I really need to fix it. Maybe I could not explain as well . 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpvefhr9dwuqjtg/Ass1Test.cpp?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provided I recommend that you use a `vector` because it can be filled with an arbitrary amount of elements. `vector` is a generic class which will handle arbitrary user defined types as elements (read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) to get understanding of generics). The variable has to be declare as member variable. If you declare it inside a method, the variable is only accessible in there and not in other methods. Here is an example how to use the vector in your context:

```
#include <vector>

class main_menu {
  private:
    std::vector<long> random_digits; 
  public:
    void random_number();
    void search_array();
};
```

In the implementation you fill the vector like this:

```
using namespace std;

void main_menu :: random_number() {
  int Size = // init it with 10 or 20;

  for(int index = 0; index < Size; index++) { 
    long random = (rand()% Size) + 1; 

    // this line fills the vector
    random_digits.push_back(random);
    cout << random << ' ';  
  } 
  cout << endl;
}
```

In the other method you can access your elements like using an array:

```
void main_menu :: search_array() {
    cout << "First element: " << random_digits[0] << endl;
}
```

Look also at the documentation of [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: The problem is I can not put 20 ! because 'Size' will add number in my array random_digit. I will get size in another function and I will use that number as 'Size' for my array random_number.

Comment: OK. You could use a `vector` instead of an array. I can edit the example if you want me to.

Comment: I will put my code here. You can download it and check it. I really need to fix it. Maybe I could not explain as well . 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpvefhr9dwuqjtg/Ass1Test.cpp?dl=0

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: How? it's the first time i asked question here. I do not know how can I make it correct.

Comment: Look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). There must be a check mark.

Answer (score 1):

```
class main_menu
{
     long random_digit[ Size ];

public:
     void random_number()
     {
         // TODO: fill random_digit array here, e.g. random_digit[ i ] = rand()
     }

     void search_array()
     {
         // TODO: access to random_digit here, e.g. some_expression = some_func( random_digit[ i ] )
     }
};
```

Comment: I will put my code here. You can download it and check it. I really need to fix it. Maybe I could not explain as well . 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpvefhr9dwuqjtg/Ass1Test.cpp?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

*random_digit[size]* Has scope and lifetime limited to the method *main_menu::random_number()* this means when that function returns the *random_digit[]* array cease to exists therefore cannot be used anymore.

A common solution is to put *random_digit[]* as member variable as suggested by user eraxillan.

Answer (score 0):

Make `random_digit` member of class `main_menu`

```
class main_menu
{

    long random_digit[Size];

    public:

    void random_number();

    void search_array();
};
```

Comment: I will put my code here. You can download it and check it. I really need to fix it. Maybe I could not explain as well . 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpvefhr9dwuqjtg/Ass1Test.cpp?dl=0